# Runtime panic when providing input data that exceeds bounded vector length

Tags: pallet, runtime

When an extrinsic has an input of for example:

`some_call(origin: OriginFor<T>, input: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<6>>)`

And calling this with input exceeding lenght 6 (ex: "1234567")

The runtime panics on validating the transaction and recovers after.

I'm not quite certain if this is actually the behaviour that is expected. Maybe the better thing to do is to make the input just a `Vec<u8>` and try to construct the boundedVector in the call itself and throw and error if it exceeds the size.

related stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/DylanVerstraete/5f47a3b0a86620fafe9a05395e519ab4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node will just not gossip that transaction. No harm being done if you run your own node.

Sure you can also construct the bounded-vec inside the call, but then the caller has to pay fees in case the construction fails. Its a different design choice.

Comment: Indeed the transaction is not gossiped, thanks for pointing this out.